# Shell script that prints file tree with size and date

Tags: bash, tree, directory-listing

I have some problems with my Synology NAS Cloud Station (like Dropbox). Somehow my local version has come out of sync with the version on the server. It's a pain to inspect the differences and get an overview. I would like to print a tree structure including size, last-modified, and created date. It will serve as a snapshot before I begin cleaning up.

I can't really program in Bash, but I hope it is OK to ask for such a script.

By the way, I can't use `tree` since it is not available on the NAS, which uses some proprietary version of Linux.

Comment: Start with "find the_path -type f -exec ls -l {} \;" This will give give the size/modified information .

Answer (score 3):

Listing of all files under the "present working directory" (`PWD="."`) is easy:

```
find . -type f -print0 | xargs -0 -I '{}' ls -la -- '{}'
```

## Edit:

One script as an example of what you need is:

```
#!/bin/sh --
if [ "$1" ] ; then
    SearchDir="$1"
fi

find ${SearchDir:=\./} \( ! -regex '.*/\..*' \) -type f |
while IFS= read -r file; do
    a="$(stat -c "%X" "$file")"
    b="$(date --date='@'"$a" "+%D")"
    c="$(stat -c "%Y" "$file")"
    d="$(date --date='@'"$c" "+%D")"
    printf "%10s %10s -- %s\n" "$b" "$d" "$file|"
done
```

Comment: Like I said, the tree command is not available on the NAS. Your first command helps though :)

Comment: You are right, `ls -Rl` does smth like what I want. But it can't show more than one of the three timestamps at a time. Also the format is far from as readable as `tree`. Thanks though.

Comment: Also giving using `find` with `-not -path '*/\.*'` excludes hidden files, if anybody needs tha. I do :D

Comment: And your solution using args also does only show one timestamp for each node.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/84509/discussion-between-binaryzebra-and-mads-skjern).

Answer (score 0):

I know, it's not what OP asked for, but installing IPKG is not a big deal on Synology NAS.

Once accomplished you might do

```
ipkg install tree
```

or use ncdu, which provides a browsable tree (not including dates, but size and count) which you can pipe through gzip for offline use:

```
ncdu -x1o- | gzip > output.gz
```